# How to add a resource file in Rider

Tags: jetbrains-rider

How to add Excel file as.net resource in Rider ide?

[image]

I can add an item through the Localization Manager

[image]

but I do not know how to fill out the type/value.

And how to change the resource to public(not internal)?

Thanks

Comment: you can make yor class and properties public on yourResources.Designer.cs file. however, when you edit it from "Localization Manager" it will probably override it and make them all internal. I hope jetbrains introduces access editing from manager like VS